# How to set url params in a POST request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url, parameters

I have the following code. Currently the data in question is in JSON. However, I have been told that this should not be a JSON payload, but should be URL parameters. I am struggling to figure out how to change this to URL params?

```
request.post({
    url: "https://testardor.jelurida.com/nxt?",
    json: {
        requestType: "sendMoney",
        chain: "2",
        recipient: "ARDOR-XJRL-GPRK-QRUS-C73SE",
        amountNQT: "100000000",
        secretPhrase: "password",
        feeNQT: "1000000",
        deadline: "60"
        }
    ,
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            console.log(body);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you are sending the POST request then you don't need to pass anything as URL parameters because you can send that as JSON payload.

Comment: So as far as you can tell it should work as above?

Comment: Yes, it should work if don't have any other errors.

Comment: See this example: https://community.apigee.com/questions/20474/how-do-i-call-a-post-request-with-form-parameters.html basically encoding the URL with the correctly formatted string ?field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3... and URL friendly characters.

Comment: if we are talking about post request nothing is in the url. If the endpoint expect get request then everything is inside the url. What is the endpoint setup?

Comment: The endpoint expects a POST request. Some documentation: https://ardordocs.jelurida.com/Accounts#Send_Money

Answer (score 1):

May be you can write an utility function like,

```
    function giveURLParams(obj) {
        var string = "?"
        for(var i= 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length;i++){
            if(i){
                string += "&"
            }
            string += Object.keys(obj)[i] + "=" + obj[Object.keys(obj)[i]];
       }
       return string
     }
```

You can call this function with your json object as argument to this function.